# ng-click does not work for second time with ng-hide interaction

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two buttons and only 1 of them appears at a time. First one is called "Offline mode" other one is "Online mode". They appear like this on HTML:

```
<a ng-hide="offlineMode == true" ng-click="offlineMode()">Offline Mode</a> 
<a ng-show="offlineMode == true" ng-click="onlineMode()">Online Mode</a>
```

When I click to "Offline mode" for the first time it successfuly swaps into "Online mode" button. When I click "Online mode" after that it swaps back to "Offline mode". After this the button becomes unclickable. It does not enter inside the function.

JS:

```
$scope.offlineMode = function() {
    $scope.offlineMode = true;
    // do other things
};

$scope.onlineMode = function() {
    $scope.offlineMode = false;
    // do other things
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because both the function and flag variable have the same name `offlineMode`

See console for this error:

```
v2.offlineMode is not a function
```

**Fix:**
Simply rename the boolean variable to `offline`(or something else)

```
  $scope.offlineMode = function() {
      $scope.offline = true;
      // do other things
  };

  $scope.onlineMode = function() {
      $scope.offline = false;
      // do other things
  };
```

ANd update the html accordingly

```
<a href="#" ng-hide="offline" ng-click="offlineMode()">Offline Mode</a><br> 
<a href="#" ng-show="offline" ng-click="onlineMode()">Online Mode</a>
```

Notice the changes in `ng-hide` and `ng-show`.  You dont need to evaluate `offline` with `true` each time.

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/X78W2zfMKE5ppvFsJyp3?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

No need to create two buttons and two functions. You can do it in simple way like this -

```
<a ng-click="switchMode()">Switch Mode</a>
```

JS:

```
$scope.offlineMode = true;
$scope.switchMode = function() {
    $scope.offlineMode = !$scope.offlineMode;
};
```

and if you want to change the button text you can do it like this:

```
<a ng-click="switchMode()">
  <span ng-if="offlineMode">Online Mode</span>
  <span ng-if="!offlineMode">Offline Mode</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why it's not working, but consider using this approach:

```
<a ng-click="toggle()">{{caption}}</a> 

$scope.online = true;
$scope.caption = 'Offline Mode';
$scope.toggle = function() {
  $scope.online = !$scope.online;
  $scope.caption = $scope.online ? 'Offline Mode' : 'Online Mode';
  if ($scope.online) {
    // do other things
  } else {
    // do other things
  }
}
```